# scrollTop not working in browsers other than Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The `scrollTop` function in jQuery for select list is working only in Firefox. In other browsers it's not working.

For example

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
...
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>

$('#mySelect').click(function(){
         $(this).scrollTop(150);
});
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this problem so it works across all browsers?

Comment: Do you want to scroll the select list contents programmatically?

Comment: Your JavaScript is executing correctly, correct? Meaning if you add an Alert before it, does that show up?

Comment: Yes, I want scroll the select list contents programmatically.

Comment: @Seth, the javascript is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#mySelect').click(function(){
    var $options = $(this).find("option");
    $options.eq(($options.length)/2)[0].selected = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the select box doesn't support a click event in some browser? I'm assuming you want the browser to scroll to the that section of the page and then let them make a selection. You could try a `change` or `focus` event instead.

Comment: I've tried with change and focus, alert statement is working only scrollTop is not working. In Firefox is working fine.